# Processing large amount of rows chunked / unbuffered

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

Consider reading through all rows of a large table with MySQL Connector/C++:

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(
                 stmt->executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM table"));
while (res->next()) {
    handle(res->getUInt64(1), res->getDouble(2));
}
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html):

> As of this writing, MySQL Connector/C++ returns buffered results for
>   the `Statement` objects. Buffered result sets are cached on the client.
>   The driver will always fetch all the data no matter how big the result
>   set is. Future versions of the connector is expected to return
>   buffered and unbuffered results for the Statement objects.

This is in accordance with my observation. On smaller tables (~1e8 rows), it takes 3 minutes before the first `handle`, the rest completes in 7 seconds. For larger tables (~1e10 rows), it just keeps gobbling up more memory before it runs out of memory.

**How can such queries be handled without running out of memory while being reasonably efficient with concise code?**

I must say I find it hard to believe there should is no transparent solution. It seems such an obvious optimization to do chunked streaming of the result within the MySQL layer.

Note: `handle` is in a library, much faster than the MySQL server can provide data. It must process rows in natural order, so it cannot be parallelized.

Comment: This appears to be doable now. See `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-cpp/en/news-1-0-5.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Connector C++ Unbuffered ResultSet C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097354/mysql-connector-c-unbuffered-resultset-c)

Comment: It's sad that the documentation makes no mention of performance / memory characteristics of `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. I'm a bit reluctant to close as duplicate because the other question is less specific. Also there is still no answer regarding a chunked streaming solution.

Comment: Agreed, not sure why the docs are so bad.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it, not exactly transparently, would be to do the chunking on the client, so getting the count of the total rows and use the LIMIT keyword in the query combined with a loop to launch multiple queries for a chunk size that has acceptable memory usage. You'd have to be sure that the table contents was not changing in the meantime to be able to do that.