# Mysql Connector C++ Unbuffered ResultSet C++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a table that holds large data.
I want to fetch all the data and process them one by one.

According to the documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html

> The API for fetching result sets is identical for (simple) statements
>   and prepared statements. If your query returns one result set, use
>   sql::Statement::executeQuery() or
>   sql::PreparedStatement::executeQuery() to run your query. Both methods
>   return sql::ResultSet objects. By default, Connector/C++ buffers all
>   result sets on the client to support cursors.

It says by default it buffers all results sets on the client.
How can I disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the statement, you can define the type of the result set. Using `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` leads to unbuffered result sets as defined in [mysql release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-cpp/en/news-1-0-5.html):

> ... Implemented getResultSetType() and setResultSetType() for
>   Statement. Uses TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, which means unbuffered result set
>   and TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, which means buffered result set.

Hope it helps.